# Search for product displays based on info from products in Commerce

Tags: 7, commerce

I have a website with various articles of clothing for sale. Here's how I have it set up:

Product Display content items:

```
Mens V-Neck Tshirt
Mens Tank Top Tshirt
Womens Tshirt
Childrens Tshirt
```

Product content items (in Commerce):

```
Mens V-Neck Tshirt - Red - Large
Mens V-Neck Tshirt - Blue - Large
Mens Tank Top Tshirt - Green - Small
```

etc...

**Colors** (**Red**, **Blue**, **Green**) and **sizes** (**Large**, **Small**, etc) are set up as Select-List fields with the *Enable this field to function as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms* option enabled.

I need to allow my shoppers to search for shirts that have **Red** as an available color, or that have **Small** as an available size. So if they searched for shirts that are **Red** and **Small**, they would receive no results based on the product list above, but if they search for **Green** and **Small**, they would see the `Mens Tank Top Tshirt` product display item in their search results.

How can I set this up? With Views/exposed filters, perhaps? Or...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Commerce Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_search_api) module. Basically you are gonna have to set up Facets to achieve what you want.

This screen cast [here](http://commerceguys.com/blog/commerce-module-tuesday-commerce-search-api) walks you through on which modules you have to enable and how to tweak your configurations.